# Effect on pressure for a decrease in temperature with respect to height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-statics

If I were to have a decrease in temperature with height, $T = f(z)$, I was wondering if I could calculate the pressure like so:

Could I simply combine 
$$
\frac{dP}{dz} = -\rho g,
$$
with the ideal gas law: $P=\rho RT$
To get: 
$$
\frac{dP}{dz} = -\frac{P}{RT} g
$$

Rearranged to: 
$$ \int{\frac{1}{P}dP} = -\frac{g}{R} \int \frac{1}{T} dz,$$
then we can say $ T = f(z) $ therefore:

$$ \int{\frac{1}{P}dP} = -\frac{g}{R} \int \frac{1}{T} dz$$

which leads to 
$$
\ln\left(\frac{P_2}{P_1}\right) = -\frac{g}{R} \int \frac{1}{f(z)} dz
$$

then simply rearrange for the pressure $P_2$

I was wondering if my methodology is correct, and if so, what assumptions are to be made for this to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if my methodology is correct, and if so what assumptions are to be made for this to be true.

You assumed hydrostatic equilibrium. This is invalid for the uppermost reaches of the atmosphere, and is only approximately valid for the bulk of the atmosphere. This assumption does give a good overall picture of the atmosphere (up to the turbopause), but it misses key impacts such as weather.

You factored the gas constant $R$ out of the integral as a constant. It's not constant. Hot, humid air has a higher specific gas constant than does dry air. Simplifying the integral by treating the gas constant as constant misses some physics, but it does give a reasonable picture, and a better picture than obtained by treating temperature as constant as well.

The gravitational constant $g$ also is not constant. It decreases with altitude, so strictly speaking, you shouldn't have factored $g$ out of the integral. This is a tiny, tiny effect.